# How to create HTTPClient in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am creating connection through httpclient. But [BlackBerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry) does not support the Java httpclient class. What would the code look like to create a connection through httpclient to a server?

Comment: What happens when you try to use httpclient?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;

public class HTTPClient {
    public static String getPage(String url) {
        String response = "";

        try {
            StreamConnection s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);

            InputStream input = s.openInputStream();

            byte[] data = new byte[256];
            int len = 0;
            StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

            while( -1 != (len = input.read(data))) {
                raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
            }

            response = raw.toString();

            input.close();
            s.close();
        } catch(Exception e) { }

        return response;
    }
}
```